# Ruby regex get the word combo separated by period

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to use Ruby regex to get word combo like below.
In a example below I only need cases 1-4, * marked them in caps for easy testing. Word in the middle (`dbo, bcd`) could be anything or nothing like in case#3. I have  trouble how to  get that double period case#3 working. It's also good to get standalone `SALES` as word too but probably it's too much for one regex ?Tx all guru .
This is my script which partially working, need add `alpha..SALES`

```
 s = '1 alpha.dbo.SALES    2 alpha.bcd.SALES    3 alpha..SALES    4 SALES
      bad cases 5x alpha.saleS  6x  saleSXX'

 regex = /alpha+\.+[a-z]+\.?sales/ix
 puts 'R: ' + s.scan(regex).to_s

##R: ["alpha.dbo.SALES", "alpha.bcd.SALES"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '1 alpha.dbo.SALES    2 alpha.bcd.SALES    3 alpha..SALES    4 SALES
bad cases 5x alpha.saleS  6x  saleSXX 7x alpha.abc.SALES.etc'

regex = /(?<=^|\s)(?:alpha\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:sales)(?=\s|$)/i
puts 'R: ' + s.scan(regex).to_s
```

Output:

```
R: ["alpha.dbo.SALES", "alpha.bcd.SALES", "alpha..SALES", "SALES"]
```

Comment: Tx, Matt. Map is new thing for me, sorry can't give you points, looks like i'm not qualified yet). Best.M

Comment: regex = /alpha+\.+[a-z]*+\.?\bsales\b|(?<!\.)\bsales\b/ix

Comment: Fyi here are 5 examples that match your proposed regex, which my solution filters out: `XXXalpha.XXX.SALES alphaaaa.aaa.SALES alpha.yyy.SALES.XXX #SALES #SALES.XXX`

Comment: Tx much Matt!! It's real science!

Comment: Hi Matt, do you  know if possible to plug this map regex into loop to process, I had with old s.scan(regex).  I put more code into UPDATED section. Tx much again. M

Comment: I don't see the UPDATED section. But in general it is best to open a new post for a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
r = /
    (?<=\d[ ])        # match a digit followed by a space in a positive lookbehind
    (?:               # begin a non-capture group
      \p{Alpha}+        # match one or more letters
      \.                # match a period
      (?:               # begin a non-capture group
        \p{Alpha}+      # match one or more letters
        \.              # match a period
        |               # or
        \.              # match a period
      )                 # end non-capture group
    )?                  # end non-capture group and optionally match it
    SALES             # match string
    (?!=[.\p{Alpha}]) # do not match a period or letter (negative lookahead)
    /x                # free-spacing regex definition mode.

s.scan(r)
  #=> ["alpha.dbo.SALES", "alpha.bcd.SALES", "alpha..SALES", "SALES"]
```

This regular expression is customarily written as follows.

```
r = /
    (?<=\d )(?:\p{Alpha}+\.(?:\p{Alpha}+\.|\.))?SALES(?!=[.\p{Alpha}])/
```

In free-spacing mode the space must be put in a character class (`[ ]`); else it would be stripped out.

Comment: Good idea to use `?:` to avoid capturing. I used it in my answer, thanks! :)

Comment: @Matt So you improve your solution based on someone else's and you don't even upvote his? Not very cool.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness That's because he misunderstood the question. One of the requirements was that the matched string end in "SALES". Where is that in the regex? Giving credit in a comment is what is appropriate.

Comment: @Matt, I assumed that there is nothing special about the word "SALES"; that it could be any word, and was referenced in the question as pertaining to the particular example given. It's not clear, however, whether that specific word is required (tand that should be clarified in the question.I certainly don't have a problem borrowing from other solutions, something I do from time-to-time. After all, our objective is produce the most useful answers to readers.

Comment: Yes, Tx Cary for you post which is very educational , @Matt is correct it's not clear yet, , <Sales> is  Table.Name which is required and have it in the loop, but  Alpha is literal.

Comment: I updated my answer to require the literal, `"SALES"`.

Comment: Tx again all !!!! Cary and Matt,  @Matt your recent solution like below without map solved my next question, it works perfectly.  Best M

Comment: regex = /(?<=^|\s)(?:alpha\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:sales)(?=\s|$)/ix   Matt (c) !!!!